# jQuery - Remove table col with specific value

Tags: jquery, find

i hava a problem and need your help. I have some tables like this structure:

```
------------------------------------------------------
|       | Col A  | Col B  | Col C  | Col D  | Col E  |
------------------------------------------------------
| Row 1 | 150    | 0.00   | 2000   | 700    | 0.00   |
------------------------------------------------------
| Row 2 | 175    | 0.00   | 2000   | 700    | 100    |
------------------------------------------------------
| Row 3 | 25     | 0.00   | 1000   | 700    | 0.00   |
------------------------------------------------------
```

I have to find and remove in each table every column which contains in every row the value "0.00". In the example above, i wan't to delete "Col B" completly. "Col E" should stay there, because it has in Row 2 a non-zero value.

I started with this, but no idea how to finish that. I think i do it to difficult. Have someone a nice idea to help me? Thanks a lot :-)

```
    searchForZeroCells: function() {

    var obj                 = this;
    var TableCleanUp        = jQuery(obj.settings.selector.TableCleanUp);

    TableCleanUp.each(function() {
        var currentTable = jQuery(this);
        var currentTableRow = currentTable.find('tr');
        var rowsPerTable = currentTableRow.length;

        var rowArray = [];

        currentTableRow.each(function() {
            var currentRow = jQuery(this);
            var cellsPerRow = currentRow.find('td').length;

            if(cellsPerRow > 0) {
                currentRow.find('td').each(function() {
                    var currentCell = jQuery(this);
                    if(jQuery.trim(currentCell.text()) == '0.00') {
                        rowArray.push(currentCell.index());
                        console.log(rowArray);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Comment: Do you (or will you) have any `colspan=` or `rowspan=`?  Cause these mess up table "columns" for data.

Comment: How is your table generated?  This looks like it could handled in the source much more easily (especially if there are any col/row spans)

Comment: hi, no i have no colspan or rowspan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way to remove a column, using

```
td:nth-child(idx)
```

Looping from last column to ColA so that any remove()s don't affect later `nth-child` checks:

```js
var cols = $("#table>thead>tr>th").length;
var head = $("#table>thead")
var tbl = $("#table>tbody")

for (var col=cols;col>1;--col)
{
    //console.log(col)
    var rowCells = tbl.find("td:nth-child(" + col + ")");
    var valueCells = rowCells.filter(function() {
       return $(this).text() != "0.00";
    });
    if (valueCells.length == 0)
    {
        console.log("remove", col);
        head.find("th:nth-child(" + col + ")").remove();
        rowCells.remove();
    }
}
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid #CCC; padding: 2px 4px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th><th>Col A</th><th>Col B</th><th>Col C</th><th>Col D</th><th>Col E</th><th>Col F</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr><td>Row 1</td><td>150</td><td>0.00</td><td>2000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td><td>175</td><td>0.00</td><td>2000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td><td> 75</td><td>0.00</td><td>1000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id='table'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th></th><th>Col A</th><th>Col B</th><th>Col C</th><th>Col D</th><th>Col E</th><th>Col F</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr><td>Row 1</td><td>150</td><td>0.00</td><td>2000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 2</td><td>175</td><td>0.00</td><td>2000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>100</td></tr>
<tr><td>Row 3</td><td> 75</td><td>0.00</td><td>1000</td><td>700</td><td>0.00</td><td>0.00</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on freedomn-nm's solution, here is my working version. I added a second condition which checks for empty cells, too:

```
removeUnwantedData: function() {

    var obj                 = this;
    var TableCleanUp        = jQuery(obj.settings.selector.TableCleanUp);

    TableCleanUp.each(function() {
        var currentTable = jQuery(this);
        var cols = currentTable.find("> thead > tr > th").length;
        var head = currentTable.find("> thead")
        var tbl = currentTable.find("> tbody")

        for (var col = cols; col > 1; --col)
        {
            //console.log(col)
            var rowCells = tbl.find("td:nth-child(" + col + ")");
            var valueCellsZero = rowCells.filter(function() {
                return $.trim($(this).text()) != "0.00";
            });
            var valueCellsEmpty = rowCells.filter(function() {
                return $.trim($(this).text()) != "";
            });
            if (valueCellsZero.length == 0) {
                //console.log("remove zero cells: ", col);
                head.find("th:nth-child(" + col + ")").remove();
                rowCells.remove();
            }
            if (valueCellsEmpty.length == 0) {
                //console.log("remove empty cells: ", col);
                head.find("th:nth-child(" + col + ")").remove();
                rowCells.remove();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: You might like to combine your tests into a single text `return $.trim($(this).text()) != "0.00" && $.trim($(this).text()) != ""` so that it picks up columns that are a mixture of 0.00/blank.